# Универсальный способ получения ссылки на страницу, на которую перенаправляет определённый url

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Добрый день. У меня есть определённая страница. Я делаю parse, в итоге получаю определённые ссылки. Если перейти по этим ссылкам, то ты перенаправляешься на другую страницу. Мне нужен url этой другой страницы, на которую происходит перенаправление. Сначала я делал что-то вроде такого

```
new URL("https://somepage.com").openConnection().getHeaderField("Redirection");
```

Но к моему глубочайшему сожалению у некоторых ссылок getHeaderFields() может отличаться и ссылка на интересующую меня страницу может иметь HeaderField не Redirection, а RedirectionURL, к примеру. Мне нужен какой-то универсальный способ получения url страницы, на которую происходит переход при переходе на перенаправляющую страницу.

Comment: есть ли возможность использовать в проекте selenium webdriver? да, будет дольше, но зато полный контроль на данными и выполнением прохода по страницам

Comment: @DaysLikeThis можно попробовать это Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).execute().url()